# Docker-compose pass dynamic parameters

Tags: docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose to build and run an application. 
My problem is to pass to the docker-compose.yml file a parameter in order to define a dynamic *image* containing the product version number.

This is the docker compose build command where I set the VERSION parameter: 
**docker-compose build --force-rm --build-arg VERSION=5.5.0.15**

This is my docker compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  igfsbuynowsrv:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: igfsbuynow
    image: igfsbuynow:${VERSION}
    ports:
      - 18080:18080
      - 18081:18081
    environment:
      - VERSION=$VERSION
```

I receive the warning message: 
*WARNING: The VERSION variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.*

Culd you please indicate to me how to pass into the docker-compose.yml file a dynamic VERSION parameter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Build-args and envirnonment variables are not the same thing. You want to set an environment variable.

Comment: Ok but there is a way to pass a parameter to doker-compose.yml file in the build phase as per my above example?